# How to pass additional arguments in $form['#after_build']

Tags: 7, forms

```
function custom_third_level_auto_suggest_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
$form['#after_build'] = 'custom_third_level_auto_suggest_widget_selection_afterbuild';

}
```

I need to pass $element across #after_build function, how I can implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Most of callbacks like `#after_build` will received automatically 2 arguments: $elements and $form_state, like this :

```
my_callback_after_build($element, &$form_state){
//...
}
```

So you simply have to push your var in the form_state var from where you add your callback :

```
function custom_third_level_auto_suggest_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
   $form['#after_build'] = 'custom_third_level_auto_suggest_widget_selection_afterbuild';
   $form_state['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

And you'll get it in the form_state var of your callback like this:

```
function custom_third_level_auto_suggest_widget_selection_afterbuild($form, &$form_state){
   var_dump($form_state['foo']); //will print "bar"
}
```